# following packages have unmet dependencies : java related

Tags: 20.04, java, jre

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-8-jre-headless : Depends: ca-certificates-java but it is not installable
                          Depends: java-common (>= 0.28) but it is not installable
```

---

```
tanmay@tan:/usr/bin$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease            
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rock-core/qt4/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:7 http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu focal InRelease          
Reading package lists... Done                     
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/source/Sources' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease' does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/source/Sources' as repository 'http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu focal InRelease' does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)
```

Unable to install in 20.04. New to ubuntu. Thanks in advance.

```
Unpacking JRE ... Starting Installer ... Exception in thread "main"                java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/tanmay/{name removed}.12871.dir/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so: libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1872)     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)   at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:67)     at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:47)     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at sun.nio.ch.Util.load(Util.java:485)  at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.<clinit>(IOUtil.java:351)  at sun.nio.ch.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:48)   at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.<clinit>(FileChannelImpl.java:1204)   at java.io.RandomAccessFile.getChannel(RandomAccessFile.java:278)   at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.util.SingleInstance.check(SingleInstance.java:74)     at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.util.SingleInstance.checkForCurrentLauncher(SingleInstance.java:31)   at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.checkSingleInstance(UnixLauncher.java:91)    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:60)
```

Followed [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories), and trying to install *.sh file. Got the error mentioned above. This is the first time i am using askubuntu. I will try  to address my query in a better syntax and semantics.

Comment: Please show us `sudo apt update` add this to your question

Comment: added @nobody..

Comment: restore default sources.list https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories    control entries in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/  and try again after command `sudo apt update`